# Wordpress - Child theme name change

Tags: php, wordpress

If I edit the folder name of'child theme', why does the rest of the css or some contents break? Is it possible to edit the name so that the content is not damaged?
(I'm not good at development. Sorry if my question was rude. However, I eagerly ask for help.)

Development environment: Windows

Comment: If you rename the folder name you have to set your theme again in appearance->theme

Answer (score 0):

Open child theme style.css file and change Theme Name value to your custom theme name also. Save the applied changes.
[image]